# Use single StylesContext when importing component from custom MUI-based library

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, shadow-dom, react-context

I have an application (let's call it `frontend`) importing a custom library of React components (`design-system`) that's Material UI based.

In the `frontend` app, I have a ShadowDOM-contained component (using `react-shadow`) that I want to import a Button component from `design-system` to. I wrapped the whole tree inside ShadowDOM with StylesProvider that I passed a custom instance of `jss` to (with different injectionPoint, so the styles from inside that tree are attached not at the head of the document, but inside the ShadowDOM.

The issue I have is, that `frontend` uses its own copy of StylesProvider from `@material-ui/styles` package (I have no need to install the whole `@material-ui/core` as all components should be imported from `design-system` instead) and `design-system` uses its own copy of StylesProvider from `@material-ui/core`, resulting in a situation, where the Button is being wrapped with another StylesProvider by MUI because it doesn't detect any styles context available (and it doesn't, because MUI creates the context in global scope of StylesProvider.js file - so there are two different contexts that do the same), resulting in Button having access to default JSS instance where the insertionPoint is pointing to document head.

[image: Diagram showing relations between apps, react components and contexts]

What I'd like to achieve is, have MUI not create another styles context for every single component imported from `design-system` but use the one I defined in `frontend` - without passing it as a prop manually to every component imported. I considered adding `@material-ui/styles` on top of `@material-ui/core` to `design-system` and adding it to webpack's "externals" (so, theoretically, only one StylesProvider.js would be used and in turn - one context), but I was hoping there's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:**

Just adding `@material-ui/styles` to externals in `design-system`'s webpack config was enough (even if you don't add it explicitly as dependency, `@material-ui/core` depends on it and will use it anyway, so it works).

**Long answer:**

My setup is such that the "main" entrypoint in package.json of `design-system` points to `dist/index.js` (so, already bundled/minified version of the library). Without adding `@material-ui/styles` to "externals" in webpack config, it was bundled along the whole library, so at this point, whatever I did there would always be two copies of StylesProvider.js:

[image: Diagram showing two copies of @material-ui/styles included]

One solution is to mark `@material-ui/styles` as external - this way, it won't be bundled in dist/index.js and instead, expected to be available during runtime (and it is):

[image: Diagram showing how @material-ui/styles is loaded runtime from frontend]

Besides the aforementioned solution, there's also another one that worked - pointing "main" entry in package.json to "src/index.ts" instead. It made the `frontend` webpack treat it as a part of `frontend` code, instead of separate library:

[image]

As a bonus, it ended up with the final bundle being smaller (as common dependencies weren't duplicated). One minus of this approach was, however, that each `frontend` build had to also rebuild `design-system`, which increased the total build time.